# Error on returning list of string vb.net desktop application

Tags: vb.net, return-value, generic-list

i'm trying to create a ntier desktop application using vb.net 2008.I'm trying this code

Presentation Layer

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Pos.Pos.BLL
Imports Pos.Pos.DAL
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class frmLogin
Private user As New User()
Private CnnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data " + "Source= " + Application.StartupPath + "\pos.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=pos"

Private cnn As New OleDbConnection()
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    'Try

    'menu = user.getMenu()
    Dim menu As New List(Of String)
    If cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Close()
    End If
    Try
        Dim jabatan As String = user.login(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text)
        MsgBox(jabatan)
        menu = user.getMenu(jabatan)
        'Dim strCommand As String = "select Menu from tblJabatan where JabatanName='" + jabatan + "'"
        'cnn.ConnectionString = CnnStr
        'cnn.Open()
        'Dim Comm As New OleDbCommand(strCommand, cnn)
        'Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = Comm.ExecuteReader
        'Do While dr.Read
        'menu.Add(dr(0).ToString)
        'Loop
        If Not menu Is Nothing Then
            For Each Str As String In menu
                MsgBox(Str)
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox("Tidak ditemukan data")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Business Layer

```
Public Class User
    Private User As New daUser()
    Private m_UserID As Integer
    Private m_User As String
    Private m_Pwd As String
    Private m_Jabatan As String

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    '''<summary>
    '''ID User
    '''</summary>
    Public Property UserID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_UserID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_UserID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<summary>
    '''Username
    '''</summary>
    Public Property Username() As String
        Get
            Return m_User
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_UserID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<summary>
    '''Password
    '''</summary>
    Public Property Password() As String
        Get
            Return m_Pwd
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Pwd = value
        End Set
    End Property
    '''<summary>
    '''Jabatan
    '''</summary>
    Public Property Jabatan() As String
        Get
            Return m_Jabatan
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Jabatan = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Sub add()

        User.add(Me)
    End Sub

    Public Function login(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As String
        Return User.Login(Username, Password)
    End Function

    Public Function getMenu(ByVal Jabatan As String) As List(Of String)
        Return User.getMenu(Jabatan)
    End Function

End Class
```

Data Layer

```
Public Class daUser
Public Sub New()
        cnn.ConnectionString = CnnStr
        cnn.Open()
    End Sub
  Public Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As String
        'Dim role As String
        If cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Close()
        End If
        Try
            Dim strCom As String = "select Jabatan from tblUser where Username='" + username + "' and Password='" + password + "'"
            cnn.ConnectionString = CnnStr
            cnn.Open()
            Dim Comm As New OleDbCommand(strCom, cnn)
            Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = Comm.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read
                role = dr(0).ToString
            End While
            cnn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.ToString
        Finally
        End Try
        Return role
    End Function

    Public Function getMenu(ByVal jabatan As String) As List(Of String)
        If cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Close()
        End If
        Try
            Dim strCommand As String = "select Menu from tblJabatan where JabatanName='" + jabatan + "'"
            cnn.ConnectionString = CnnStr
            cnn.Open()
            Dim Comm As New OleDbCommand(strCommand, cnn)
            Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = Comm.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read
                menu.Add(dr("Menu").ToString)
            End While
            cnn.Close()

        Catch er As OleDb.OleDbException


        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
        End Try
        Return menu
    End Function
    End Class
```

When i run it,it gives me this warning

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object 
>   at Pos.frmLogin.btnLogin_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects
>   \POS\Pos\Form\frmLogin.vb:line 39

Please point me what mistake did i made and how to solve it

The code for the the error is

```
For Each Str As String In menu
MsgBox(Str)
Next
```

By the way what i want to achieve is how to get the data as a List(Of String),because if i put the getMenu function into the presentation layer directly,it gives me the data as i expected..Also if i return as a string instead of List(Of String),it gives me the single data.
Thanks...

Comment: The error is occurring in the `btnLogin_Click` event ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object at `Pos.frmLogin.btnLogin_Click`"). Please post that section of code.

Comment: Hi Cody,line 39 is                                                  For Each Str As String In menu. Thanks

Comment: It's still very difficult for me to see what's happening without the full methods and *names* in your code. I'm having a hard time getting a feel for how your project is laid out. The problem is clearly happening in the presentation layer, so that's the code we really need to see. If you don't want (or feel like it's too much) to post it all here, you can paste it on [Pastie](http://www.pastie.org) and link to it here.

Comment: @Cody I have paste the full presentation layer code here,i get null data as the result.It seems that menu.Add(dr("Menu").ToString) in the data layer was not working,because if i return as a string.I get the results..Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you haven't instantiated menu.  Change the declaration for menu to

```
Dim menu As New List(Of String)
```

Comment: @yesaya handoyo - No problem.  If the answer helped, marking it as the appropriate answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Someone should probably tell you that you have quite a few things wrong with this. Firstly and most importantly, building Dynamic SQL like that will make your application vulnerable to SQL injection. The other thing is that exception details should not be returned to the user. By doing this you have basically given the caller an "oracle" to use in conjunction with the SQL vulnerability. With just these two problems, anyone with basic SQL knowledge can do whatever they want to your data.

There are a few other items (empty finally, empty catches, not using "Using", object naming collisions, etc), but the security items are much more important.

Comment: Hi StingyJack,thanks for the input,i will change the codes,by the way could you point how to get the data as i expected?If i put the getMenu function directly into the presentation layer,i get the data..Thanks a lot..

Comment: When replying, use the convention "@username" to get the attention of the poster. I dont see any code in the business layer that instantiates the class. This is required, unless you are using Shared/static functions

Comment: i've edited the code,but i still can't get the results as i expected..Thank you..

Comment: @yesaya handoyo - perhaps you should update the code in your above example, so I can see what you are currently trying to do.

Comment: I have updated the presentation layer code,as the business and data layer are the same..Thanks...